# creating a plugin to disable the save and continue button in customer but its not working....want to know am i using right approach?

Tags: magento2

```
namespace User\Role\Plugin;


use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar as ToolbarContext;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;


class Change 

{

public function beforePushButtons(

        ToolbarContext $toolbar,
        AbstractBlock $context,
        ButtonList $buttonList
    ) {
        if (!$context instanceof \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit) {
            return [$context, $buttonList];
        }
          $buttonList->remove('save_and_continue');
        return [$context, $buttonList];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an answer 
class Change
{

```
public function aroundgetButtonData(\Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\SaveButton $subject, \Closure $proceed)
{
    $objectManager  = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $obj = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session');
    $roleData = $obj->getUser()->getRole()->getData();
    $roleName = $roleData['role_name'];
     if($roleName == 'nonadmin')         
        return null;
     else
        $result = $proceed();
        return $result;
}
```

}

enjoy coding....